# Sidekiq can not find object with ID when worker is calling from after_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, sidekiq

```
class ContactEmail < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :check_existence_of_user

  private

  def check_existence_of_user
    ContactEmailCheckWorker.perform_async(id)
  end
end

class ContactEmailCheckWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :background_job

  def perform(contact_email_id)
    # sleep 1.seconds
    ce = ContactEmail.find(contact_email_id)
    # ....
  end
end
```

I have this error:

> Couldn't find ContactEmail with 'id'=426

But after sidekiq try again this job and it's ok, find it. 
When I uncomment sleep it's working. Where is the problem? Transaction problem with after_ callback?

Comment: try use: after_commit callback

Comment: More information: http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/695-use-after_commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use **after_commit** callback. More [information](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/695-use-after_commit).

Example:

```
class ContactEmail < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :check_existence_of_user
```